# What documents should I include in UK visitor visa application?

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, moroccan-citizens

I'm from Morocco and planning to apply to visit my British husband in the UK.

Do I need more support documents in addition to these: 6 months of bank statements, 6 months of pay slips, letter from my job, permission for holiday from job, my husband's passport, letter of invitation from him, his bank statements, marriage certificate.

Do I need to provide more support documents, such as photographs of us together?Is there anything else that can help?

Comment: Don't forget information about your accommodation (address), what your budget is and what you're going to do whilst in the UK. Also you need to state somewhere that you intend to get travel insurance (thus not relying on public/NHS funds).

Comment: You mean accommodation in Morocco or the one I'm going to stay  in the UK?

Comment: Although you do need to mention your address in Morocco, they are primarily interested in the accommodation in the UK. Also include any properties, assets, family you can include, to demonstrate you have a reason to return after your visit to the UK.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you’re applying for a Standard Visit Visa you should follow this guide https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/549692/Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_English_version.pdf I’d consider including evidence of property ownership / rental in your home country; the guide states that photographs are not required unless specifically requested.